# A simple explanation of what is LDA Classification

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

I am finding it hard to understand the process of Linear discriminant analysis (LDA), and I was wondering if someone could explained it with a simple step by step process in English. I understand LDA is closely related to principal component analysis (PCA). but I have no idea how it gives all the probabilities with a grate precision. And how the training data is related to the actual dataset. I have refer few documents and i don't get much idea. It make more confusing and complicated.

Answer (score 4):

**PCA (Principal Component Analysis)** is unsupervised or what is the same, it does not use class-label information. Therefore, discriminative information is not necessarily preserve.

- Minimizes the projection error.
- Maximizes the variance of projected points.

  *Example*: Reducing the number of features of a face (*Face detection*).

**LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis):** A PCA that takes class-labels into consideration, hence, it's supervised.

- Maximizes distance between classes.
- Minimizes distance within classes.

  *Example*: Separating faces into *male* and *female* clusters (*Face recognition*).

[image: LDA vs. PCA]

With regard to the step by step process, you can easily find an implementation in Google.

Regarding the classification:

1. Project input *x* into PCA subspace *U*, and calculate its projection *a*
2. Project *a* into LDA subspace *V*
3. Find the class with the closest center

In simple words, project the input *x* and then check from which cluster center is closer.

> Image from K. Etemad, R. Chellapa, Discriminant analysis for recognition of human faces. J. Opt. Soc. Am. A,Vol. 14, No. 8, August 1997

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Salva.... can you explain this with a text oriented example...